# Python wheeling local module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, python-wheel

I am writing a project that requires pygame.

I've installed pygame in python following the instructions from the pygame wiki.

```
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

I would like to add pygame to the wheel directory that I am creating. I am attempting to do this with the command

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=wheels/linux64 pygame
```

I have tried adding in the `--no-index`, `--find-links=https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`, `--allow-unverified pygame`, `--allow-external pygame` options.

The output is always something along the lines of not finding a package that satifies the requirement pygame.

```
Downloading/unpacking pygame
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pygame to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pygame
Storing debug log for failure in /home/eric/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I wheel my local version of pygame and add it to my wheel directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point pip to the source dir in order to make a wheel.
For example:

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
...
...
$ pip wheel pygame/
Processing ./pygame
Building wheels for collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pygame
  Stored in directory: /home/vagrant/wheelhouse
Successfully built pygame
(test)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ll /home/vagrant/wheelhouse
total 3264
drwxrwxr-x 2 vagrant vagrant    4096 Sep  6 01:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 vagrant vagrant    4096 Sep  6 01:24 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 3333795 Sep  6 01:24 pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

You cannot create wheel from installed module since it's missing the install instructions part (setup.py). For more info check [wheel's usage instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#usage).